# How to combine 2 queries using dynamic dates in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of workers and would like to understand how many and what % of workers each day were returning workers. I'm defining a returner as someone that worked anytime from the beginning of the year to the day before date in the specific row. The output I'm looking for:

```
Date, # of workers total today, # of returners, % returners
7/29 , 5, 3, 60%
7/28 , 10, 5, 50%
and so on...

For 7/29, 3 workers worked on or before 7/28 (day before).
For 7/28, 5 workers worked on or before 7/27 (day before).
```

I currently have a list of workers that came in for today and a list of workers that came in for all days before today, but I'm not sure how to put them together in one query.Currently the dates are hardcoded; but how do I run this query for each day in the last 2 months? I'm also not sure that the way I'm using dates is correct; is there a way better way other than using BETWEEN?

What I currently have:

List of workers for 1 day (the date should be dynamic depending on the date of the row):

```
select
/* date_format(CONVERT_TZ(backend_shiftgroup.ends_at,'+00:00','{UTC_OFFSET.RAW}:00'), '%X-W%v') as Week, */
backend_userprofile.name,
business.name as 'Business',
worker_id,
ends_at

from backend_shift 

join backend_shiftgroup on backend_shift.shift_group_id = backend_shiftgroup.id 
join backend_gigtemplate on backend_shift.gig_id = backend_gigtemplate.id 
join business on backend_gigtemplate.business_id = business.id
join backend_company on backend_company.id = backend_gigtemplate.company_id
join backend_userprofile on backend_shift.worker_id = backend_userprofile.id

where is_cancelled = 0 
and worker_id is not null
and ends_at BETWEEN '2020-07-28' and '2020-07-29'


group by worker_id
order by count(backend_shift.id) desc;
```

List of all workers before today:

```
select
/* date_format(CONVERT_TZ(backend_shiftgroup.ends_at,'+00:00','{UTC_OFFSET.RAW}:00'), '%X-W%v') as Week, */
count(backend_shift.id) as '# of shifts',
backend_userprofile.name,
business.name as 'Business',
worker_id,
ends_at

from backend_shift 

join backend_shiftgroup on backend_shift.shift_group_id = backend_shiftgroup.id 
join backend_gigtemplate on backend_shift.gig_id = backend_gigtemplate.id 
join business on backend_gigtemplate.business_id = business.id
join backend_company on backend_company.id = backend_gigtemplate.company_id
join backend_userprofile on backend_shift.worker_id = backend_userprofile.id

where is_cancelled = 0 
and worker_id is not null
and ends_at <= '2020-07-28'

group by worker_id
order by count(backend_shift.id) desc;
```

Comment: Sorry about that! Added Mysql to the question and tag.

Comment: The output you're looking for doesn't tally up with what you're currently trying to do in your query. You say you want '# of workers' for example, but then you're grouping on worker_id, therefore assuming you're doing this per worker. Are you also going to calculate number of returners and % as you're not currently selecting that info.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for help on. What I have today doesn't get me to the number of returners and % but thats what I'm trying to get to.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You can also set up a db/sql fiddle.  Your question also mentions two tables, but your code references many more.  That is confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the sample output at the top of the question. Does that help?

Comment: @Akina Mysql 8.0.19

Comment: *Currently the dates are hardcoded; but how do I run this query for each day in the last 2 months?* Recursive CTEs are available in your version - generate dates list "on the fly".